# (React.js) How to disable inputs until the previous input is enterred?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input element returned by an Array of strings like the image below.
How can I write the input component so that the subsequent inputs are disabled until the current input is entered by the user? Users can only start with the input from the top left then move to the right accordingly.

```
function() {

return (
<div>

  {strArr.map((item, index) => (
    <input />
  ))}
</div>
)}
```

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This sounds like terrible UX design.

Comment: It's a "guess the sentence" page and this is a required functionality by the assessment. "The order
of guessing must start from the beginning and you can only guess the next character"

Comment: So it has to the be the _correct_ input, not just any input? Can you add the rest of your code as an [mcve]? [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all set state and call it like isActive
- Second, give your input an identifier like id that can be equal to the current
- So, by default, your state will be initialized with 0;
- Set disabled property of your input dynamically, if isActive is not equal to the current state it gonna be disabled,

```
function() {
const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(0);
const handleOnInputChange = (index)=>{
setIsActive(index+1)
}
return (
<div>

  {strArr.map((item, index) => (
    <input ket={index} id={index} disabled={isActive !== index} onChange={()=>handleOnInputChange(index)}/>
  ))}
</div>
)}
```

- This gonna work if you have only to write a single character in your input

Comment: Sir, you're a genius. Wish I could be like you one day!